# Iterative subtraction, over many columns, based on condition within R

Tags: r, dplyr

My data contains statistics on the outcome of a soccer game, with 12806 observations (match outcomes) and 34 key performance indicators.

A (small) example of my data.frame is below:

```
head(Test)
  MatchID Outcome Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5
1      30    Loss    0   10    0   10    0
2      30     Win    6   13    6   13    6
3      31    Loss    8   12    3    6    3
4      31     Win   29   40    9   19    3
5      32    Loss    7   26    7   26    6
6      32     Win   11   20   11   20    9
```

For every unique "Match ID" I wish to deduct each of the losing (Outcome=="Loss" key performance indicators from the winning (Outcome=="Win") team. My data.set is not always arranged by Loss, Win, Loss, Win so completing this in a row.wise fashion may not be possible.

I have tried the following using dplyr:

```
 Differences <- Test %>% 
   group_by(MatchID) %>% 
   summarise_at( .vars = names(.)[3:7], ((Outcome == "Win") - (Outcome == "Loss")))
```

but fear I am using the wrong approach as I received the following error: `Error in inherits(x, "fun_list") : object 'Outcome' not found`

My anticipated outcome would be:

```
head(AnticipatedOutcome)
  MatchID Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5
1      30  6    3    6    3    6
3      31 21   28    6   13    0
5      32  4   -6    4   -6    3
```

Is this please possible to achieve, using dplyr?

Comment: @akrun apologies, this is updated to reflect my example.

Comment: Thank you for the update.  Can you check the updated `summarise`d output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference of two logical vectors is of the same length.  We need to subset the 'Var' columns where 'Outcome' is `"Win"`, take the `sum` of it and subtract it from those where the 'Outcome' is `"Loss"`

```
library(tidyverse)
Test %>%
    group_by(MatchID) %>%
    summarise_at(vars(starts_with('Var')),
              funs(sum(.[Outcome == "Win"]) - sum(.[Outcome == "Loss"])))
# A tibble: 3 x 6
#  MatchID  Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4  Var5
#    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1      30     6     3     6     3     6
#2      31    21    28     6    13     0
#3      32     4    -6     4    -6     3
```

---

Or another option would be to `gather` into 'long' format, get the group by difference of `sum` and `spread` it to 'wide' format

```
Test %>% 
  gather(key, val, Var1:Var5) %>% 
  group_by(MatchID, key) %>%
  summarise(val = sum(val[Outcome == "Win"]) - sum(val[Outcome == "Loss"])) %>%
  spread(key, val)
```

Comment: Thank you for both options and the patience whilst I added my updates!

Answer (score 1):

One can use `data.table` with `.SDcols` argument to summarise the data. As @akrun has mentioned in his solution, `sum` of "Loss" will be subtracted from the `sum` of "Win" for each Match.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[,lapply(.SD,function(x)sum(x[Outcome=="Win"]) - sum(x[Outcome=="Loss"])), 
   .SDcols = Var1:Var5,by=MatchID]

#    MatchID Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5
# 1:      30    6    3    6    3    6
# 2:      31   21   28    6   13    0
# 3:      32    4   -6    4   -6    3
```

**Note:** Just for the sake of exploring different ideas, but one can achieve same result in even `base-R`:

```
cbind(unique(df[1]), df[order(df$MatchID),][df$Outcome == "Win",3:7] - 
        df[order(df$MatchID),][df$Outcome == "Loss",3:7])

#   MatchID Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5
# 1      30    6    3    6    3    6
# 3      31   21   28    6   13    0
# 5      32    4   -6    4   -6    3
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text =
"MatchID Outcome Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5
1      30    Loss    0   10    0   10    0
2      30     Win    6   13    6   13    6
3      31    Loss    8   12    3    6    3
4      31     Win   29   40    9   19    3
5      32    Loss    7   26    7   26    6
6      32     Win   11   20   11   20    9",
header =TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```